# How to display the top 3 products by revenue and their share in total revenue by year?

Tags: sql

I have a DB with that tables.

1. Users (userId, age)
2. Purchases (purchaseId, userId, itemId, date)
3. Items (itemId, price).

I need to display the top 3 items by revenue (1 column), share in total revenue (2 column).

```
    Example: 
    itemid share
    1      20
    2      10 
    3      8
```

Revenue = count purchased items * price.

My code

```
SELECT Items.itemid, SUM(Items.price) FROM Purchases
LEFT JOIN Items ON Items.itemid = Purchases.itemId
WHERE strftime('%Y', Purchases.date) = '2020'
GROUP BY Items.itemid
ORDER BY Items.itemid DESC LIMIT 3
```

I do not understand how to calculate the percentage of revenue in SQL and how to display it.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT i.itemid, SUM(i.price),
       SUM(i.price) * 1.0 / SUM(SUM(i.price)) OVER () as ratio
FROM Purchases p JOIN
     Items i
     ON i.itemid = p.itemId
WHERE p.date >= '2020-01-01' AND
      p.date < '2021-01-01'
GROUP BY i.itemid
ORDER BY i.itemid DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Note the changes to the query:

- The use of table aliases, so the query is easier to write and to read.
- The date filtering uses date constants, so the optimizer can use indexes/partitions if available.
- Window functions provide the total that you want.
- A `LEFT JOIN` is unnecessary.  You need a match for items to have a total price.

Comment: Thanks, but ratio displayed as 0, other columns are displayed correctly https://imgur.com/YB3ekdD

Comment: @RoseVinnur . . . The database you are using might be using integer division.  Just multiply by 1.0.